# Django Saving form with two foreign keys

Tags: django, django-views

I am attempting to save a form that submits data (project note comments) linked to another model (project notes) via foreign key (project notes). Project notes are linked via foreign key to another model (projects). I thought I would only need to consider the immediate relationship (project notes). However from the error I am getting, I also need to process the relationship from project notes to project.

The error:

```
IntegrityError at /projects/note/1/add_project_note_comment/
insert or update on table "company_project_projectnotes" violates foreign key constraint "company_project_proj_project_id_478f433c_fk_company_p"
DETAIL:  Key (project_id)=(0) is not present in table "company_project_project".
```

The models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    description = tinymce_models.HTMLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse ('project_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class ProjectNotes(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, default=0, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ProjectNoteComments(models.Model):
    body = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    projectnote = models.ForeignKey(ProjectNotes, default=0, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notes')
```

The view:

```
class ProjectNotesCommentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ProjectNotes
    template_name = 'company_accounts/add_project_note_comment.html'
    fields = ['body']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        projectnote = get_object_or_404(ProjectNotes, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.projectnote = projectnote
        comment.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('project_detail', args=[self.kwargs.get('pk')])
```

The URL pattern:

```
path('note/<int:pk>/add_project_note_comment/', ProjectNotesCommentCreateView.as_view(), name='add_project_note_comment'),
```

The template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

  {% block content %}
  <h1>Add Comment</h1>
  
   <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input type="submit" value="save">
   </form>
  
  {% endblock content %}
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You won't have a relationship with `pk` field of the `ProjectNoteComments` with the `ProjectNote model` and the related names are same for both models, you might want to fix that.

Moreover, you are delaying commiting the form only for `ProjectNote`, but you also have to handle it for `Project` model too through backward referencing `projectnote__project` (related names may cause problem at this place.

Comment: Thanks for catching that Rifat. I made the related names unique. I am still not sure how to handle referencing the Project model.

Comment: @Finn `comment.projectnote.project` should access the project field in your `ProjectNote` model

Comment: Rifat, any suggestions on how to implement that? I am new to Django/python. I attempted a couple of things in the view but so far, I am still getting an error when I try to save the form.

Comment: Can you share the template that you are using?

Comment: Here is the template:
`{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

  {% block content %}
  <h1>Add Comment</h1>
  
   <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input type="submit" value="save">
   </form>
  
  {% endblock content %}
`